# Distributions all numeric values in python

Tags: python, kaggle

i am just doing titanic dataset machine learning problem.I seperate numerical and categorical value in  my dataset.and want to plot histogram all numerical values but i doesnt show.Can anyone help me to fix this?My code:

```
num_variable=train_data[['Age','SibSp','Parch','Fare']]
for i in num_variable.columns:
    plt.hist(num_variable[i])
    plt.title(i)
    plt.show
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI7hK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you just need to reset the plot with plt.figure() in each iteration:

```
num_variable=train_data[['Age','SibSp','Parch','Fare']]
for i in num_variable.columns:
    plt.figure()
    plt.hist(num_variable[i])
    plt.title(i)
    plt.show
```